I can't use the service layer in my Spring Boot
After some configuration, I can't use the service layer in my Spring Boot. This is my src in the control layer:
I can't use the last URL to access my data， but the first two URLs are accessible
@RestController public class hello {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleMapper articleMapper;

    @GetMapping("/getall")
    public List<Article> getAllArticles() {
        return articleMapper.find();
    }
    @GetMapping("/getArticle/{id}")
    public Article getArticleById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return articleMapper.findById(id);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public List<Article> test() {
        return articleService.list();
    } 
}

This is the error info:

org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.blog.blogend.mapper.ArticleMapper.selectList`

How can I access my service layer?

Have you actually read the error? It is complaining about the mapper not the service.

Yeah, I see it, i mean i can access the first two URLs by Mapper while the last one not.

Read the error, it tells you what is wrong. Apparently your mapping doesn't containt the properly named query (or your annotation on the mapper is wrong).

oh,I figured it out, cause the file pom.xml has some conflicts, i downloaded a plugin named Maven Helper checked it out.
